# Why did Lord Sunday get involved in taking down Lady Wednesday?

Tags: keys-to-the-kingdom

In Drowned Wednesday, we find this puzzling passage:

> ‘Saturday betrayed me! The other Trustees, save that somnolent fool Monday, called me to a meeting. I was ambushed, five Keys against my one. They stripped me of my power and I was cast down into the Border Sea, my shape lost, my appetite unsuppressed!’

This is very interesting, as elsewhere we find that Sunday never gets involved in the proceedings of other parts of the House. He is far too haughty for that. Why in this case was it different?

Comment: The sad thing about the KTTK series is that while it's based on an interesting premise, the depth was always lacking. I enjoyed reading it in my childhood, but upon rereading I realized that the characters could have been fleshed out more; the powers of the seven keys and their limitations could have been more thoroughly explored.